# Add intent in Adapter

Tags: javascript, java

I have recyelerView Adapter that have Several views (4), when I add setOnclickListener on one of them it is give me this error  **`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`** , I used Context but it also not worked. so i don't know how to do this.

**Here's my code Adapter**

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context Context;

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    /* I want add onClick in this view */
    } else if (viewType == R.id.image_home_liveImage) {

        return new LiveViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_home_container_live,
                        parent,
                        false
                ),
                Context);
    } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown view type");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    } else if (getItemViewType(position) == R.id.image_home_liveImage) {
        LiveModel liveModel = items.getLive().get(position - items.getFirstImage().size());
        ((LiveViewHolder) holder).setLiveImageData(liveModel);
        ((LiveViewHolder) holder).setOnClick(liveModel);

    }
}

 /* and here's the adapter for the view that i want to add on it */
/* Live Adapter */
static class LiveViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView liveImage;
    private final Context context;

    LiveViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        liveImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_home_liveImage);
        this.context = context;
    }

    void setLiveImageData(LiveModel liveModel) {
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(liveModel.getImageLiveInfoUrl())
                .into(liveImage);
    }

    void setOnClick(LiveModel liveModel) {
        liveImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liveModel.getLiveUrl()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

tuyu5u56u65 76u

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using context, use itemView.getContext

Your onClick method should look like this

```
        void setOnClick(LiveModel liveModel) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liveModel.getLiveUrl()));
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```